# Proving $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{p^{a_i}} \geq \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{p^{b_i}}$, when $p \geq 2$.

Tags: inequality

Suppose we are given $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{a_i} \geq  \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{b_i}$, where $a_i,b_i >0$, $\forall i$. Is  $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{p^{a_i}} \geq  \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{p^{b_i}}$, where $p \geq 2$?

The above seems to be intuitively true, but I haven't found a rigorous way to prove (or disprove) the above result. Any suggestions or pointers to relevant inequalities would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inequality isn't true in general case.

Assume $n=3$, $a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = 2$, and $b_1=1, b_2=b_3 = 4$. Then your condition for $a_i$ and $b_i$ is satisfied.

However, if your inequality is true, then

$$\frac{3}{p^2} \geq \frac{1}{p} + \frac{2}{p^4}$$

should hold for all $p \geq 2$.

But it doesn't, one of the counter example is the case $p=3$.

---

It is another approach.

If we allow an extented real number system, let $n=2$, $a_1=a_2=2$, and $b_1=1, b_2 = \infty$.

Then $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{\infty}$. 
Thus the condition for $a_i$ and $b_i$ is satisfied.

However, 
$$\frac{2}{p^2} \geq \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p^\infty} = \frac{1}{p}$$
only holds where $2 \geq p$.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not necessarily true. For example, let $n = 2$, $a_1 = 0.5$, $a_2 = 100$, $b_1 = b_2 = 1$ and $p = 2$. In this case,

$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{a_i} = 2 + .01 = 2.01 \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{b_i} = 1 + 1 = 2 \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

Thus, your first condition holds. However,

$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{p^{a_i}} = \cfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \cfrac{1}{2^{100}} < 1 \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

but

$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{p^{b_i}} = \cfrac{1}{2} + \cfrac{1}{2} = 1 \tag{4}\label{eq4}$$

As such, your second condition doesn't hold. I don't believe there is any minimum value of $p$ you would allow your second condition to hold in all cases where the first condition holds, with the answer of [Doyun Nam](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/519097/doyun-nam) giving an example of how you can show this.

Comment: Thanks. I am wondering if there is any non-trivial relation between the a_i's and the b_i's that makes this inequality true for all p greater than 2.

Comment: @Brian Yes, there actually is. One simple one which is guaranteed to work is that they be positive & that each $a_i \le b_i$, so $\frac{1}{a_i} \ge \frac{1}{b_i}$. Your first inequality will then work. Also, then $p^{a_i} \le p^{b_i}$, giving that $1/p^{a_i} \ge 1/p^{b_i}$, so your second inequality will also work. The reason why your original statement is not always true is that you were only considering the summation. If you don't require each element of $a$ to be $\le$ each $b$, you can generally (but I'm don't think always) find values of $p$ which cause your second summation to fail.

Comment: Yes, the case where the ordering holds between the a_i's and the b_i's is fairly straightforward. I am mainly interested in knowing if the result holds for more general scenarios as well. We can restrict our attention to integer a_i's, b_i's and p, and impose upper bounds on the p.

Comment: @Brian This is not my area of expertise, but I believe even with integer $a_i$, $b_i$ and $p$, including with upper bounds on $p$, the majority of situations will not hold. However, I believe some will, although it is likely difficult to quantify this, especially for larger $n$, as basically you are dealing with higher power polynomials. If you're really interested, I suggest you write another question here, stating it's an extension to this one & linking to it, where you can ask if anybody can provide any particular general conditions for your two equalities to hold.